# Squares in sequence of intervals

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to bound the number of squares appearing only in the open intervals $(k^n-k, k^n)$. Here $n$ is fixed and $k\lt T$ for some $T$.  For example, with $n=3,T=4$, the intervals are $(0,1),(6,8),(24,27)$, and among these endpoint-excluded intervals only the square $25$ appears.

How shall I approach this problem?

Comment: If $k$ is square or if $n$ is even, then you know the answer, correct?  So the remaining case is when $k$ is not square and $n$ is odd...

Comment: Yeah those cases are simple, but I was hoping for a better bound than T -sqrt(T).

Comment: What do you mean, “better”?  There are a total of $\sqrt T$ squares up to $T$ (integer part only).  There are no more and no less.  Can you describe what you are looking for?

Comment: @abiessu I mean squares in the union of the intervals (k^n-k, k^n) for all k up to T, not the squares less than T.

Comment: How about this: can you describe a square that is not in one of those intervals?  That’s probably where you want to start.

Comment: @abiessu For n=3, T =4, the intervals are (0, 1), (6, 8), and (24, 27). So only 25 is in these intervals since the intervals are open bracket.

Comment: I think that for $n$ even, there are no such squares.  What do you think?

Comment: @abiessu I agreed on that long ago. My numerical data seems to suggest that this sort of squares are fairly rare, more alog the lines of O(1) for large n.

Comment: I think this is where you might put more of this type of context into the question so that my comments or possible answer could be helpful...